# In Google Apps Script, how can I have a single function iterate over a data structure that keeps track of many different pairs of variables?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, for-loop, google-apps-script, iterator

I'm trying to figure out a way for a single function to iterate over many different pairs of variables.

Because I'm [running into limits with 45 different scripts running during the same hour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56465380/3956820), I'm instead trying  to write one script that could iterate over a data structure that keeps track of two different variables at a time, in particular, pairs of folder IDs for particular Google Drive folders.

I have a function `moveFiles`:

```
function moveFiles() {

  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxSomeParticularSourceFolderxxxxxxxxxx")

  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxSomeParticularDestinationFolderxxxxxxxxxx")

  var files = source_folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    dest_folder.addFile(file);
    source_folder.removeFile(file);

  }
}
```

What data structure could I add to this script to keep track of different pairs of folder IDs for particular source and destination folders, and how can I add the whole `moveFiles` function into a `for` loop to make it all work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function moveFiles() {
  var fldrIdA=[{src:'id',des:'id'},...];
  for(var i=0;i<fldrIdA.length;i++) {
    var srcfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(fldrIdA[i].src)
    var desfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(fldrIdA[i].des)
    var files = srcfldr.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      desfldr.addFile(file);
      srcfldr.removeFile(file);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use Advanced Drive API to do this and it could support team drives as well.

Comment: This is almost perfect. One related question: what would the proper syntax be to give each pair of `id`s their own line and leave a comment on each line to identify each pair?